# Calling a external function from within a click event and passing it an argument as array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var available=["1","2","3","4"];
  var taken=[];
  var solutions=[["1","2"],["3","4"]];      

  // external function
  function check(input){
    for(var i=0;i<solutions.length;i++){
      var result=solutions[i].every(function(elem){
              return input.includes(elem)==true;
       })
      if(result==true){
          return result;
                 }
        }
   }

  // click event
  $("table td").click(function(){
  debugger
    var removed=available.splice(available.indexOf(this.id),1);
    taken.push(removed);
    check(taken); // the call works if the array *taken* is initialize                        
                  //by hand, but doesn't work filling the array with     
                 //the push method as always return an undefined value
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I try to check an array (*taken*) filled with values derived from clicks in a table against arrays contained in the solution array. For that I made a function check  with one parameter that does that job.The array *taken* is passed as argument to the function and is filled with available values through the method push.

The scopes seem that are well because if I initialize *taken* with values that met one of the solutions the return of the function *check* is true.
But applying the push method to variable *taken* the return is always undefined, so it seems that the global *taken* is not filled with push or the types are different?.

Comment: please create a demo replicating the issue and with code you have tried so far.

Comment: Where does `availableIds` come from ? You are declaring a `var` called  `available`, but not `availableIds`.

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cortazar11/zjh3q6hz/). Try clicking two players and after click X.

Comment: sorry _availableIds_ is the global _available_.

Answer (score 1):

I found that *available.splice(available.indexOf(this.id),1)* return a object not a string, so I need to convert it to a string with toString() to make the taken array an array of strings and not an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the function call , please check your external function either it should return true or false as per your code its only return in one scenario. try with this function --

```
function check(input){
for(var i=0;i<solutions.length;i++){
var result = false;
    result=solutions[i].every(function(elem){
          return input.includes(elem)==true;
   })
      return result;
    }
```

}